# SQL Server 2012: Error converting data type nvarchar to float

Tags: sql-server-2012, insert-into

I am using SQL Server 2012. I am running a query that inserts data into a table.  I am able to successfully run the query when I comment out the INSERT INTO line, but when I run it with the `INSERT INTO` code, I get this error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 27
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

Code:

```
DECLARE 
@CurrentYear smallint,
@PriorMonth date,
@CurrentMonth date,
@NextMonth date,
@CompanyCode nvarchar(255),
@Delegate varchar(25),
@NAM varchar(2),
@Division varchar(2),
@ReportingPeriod varchar(3)

SELECT
@CurrentYear = DATEPART(YY, GETDATE()),
@PriorMonth = EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -2),
@CurrentMonth = EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1),
@NextMonth = GETDATE(),
@CompanyCode = 'JDE',
@Delegate = 'Tony Scott',
@NAM = 'US',
@Division = 'MO'

SELECT @ReportingPeriod = dd.FiscalPeriod
FROM dbo.DateDimension dd (NOLOCK)
WHERE dd.LastDayOfMonth = @CurrentMonth

INSERT INTO dbo.GRIR_Main

SELECT
    a.CompanyCode,
    PriceBlk = '',
    QtyBlk = '',
    DateBlk = '',
    TrPrt = NULL,
    POrg = '',
    PGr = '',
    [Description] = '',
    Plant = '',
    PlantDescription = '',
    PurchReq = '',
    RequistionerName = '',
    a.GLAcct,
    WBSElement = '',
    SalesOrder = '',
    Network = '',
    CostCenter = '',
    Reference = '',
    a.DocumentNo,
    a.ProfitCenter,
    a.[Concatenate],
    a.Assignment,
    a.PurchDoc,
    a.VendorType,
    Vendor = '',
    a.Name1,
    Material = '',
    ShortText = '',
    a.ABSVALAmtinLC,
    GRIRUpdated = NULL,
    a.AmountinLC,
    [Type] = '',
    PostingDate = NULL,
    a.DaysAged,
    a.EYAging,
    a.DaysAgedatMonthEnd,
    a.EYAgingatMonthEnd,
    a.RestatedPriorMonth,
    a.EYAgingPriorMonth,
    Slippage =
       CASE
           WHEN a.EYAging = a.EYAgingPriorMonth THEN '0'
           ELSE a.EYAging
       END,
    a.Category1,
    a.Analyst,
    a.ReportingPeriod,
    a.FY,
    a.Delegate,
    a.NAM,
    a.Supplier,
    a.Division,
    a.Company,
    a.CompanyFilter,
    a.BU,
    a.BusinessUnitDescription,
    a.Buyer,
    a.OrderNumber,
    a.OrderType,
    a.Line,
    a.ReceiptDate,
    a.ReceiptDoc,
    a.QuantityReceived,
    a.AmountReceived,
    a.QuantityVouchered,
    a.AmountVouchered,
    a.QuantityOpen,
    a.AmountOpen,
    a.CurCod,
    a.BUName,
    a.Item,
    a.GRIRPeriod,
    a.Div
FROM
(SELECT
    Delegate = @Delegate,
    NAM = @NAM,
    Assignment = CAST(j.[Order #] AS VARCHAR) + ' - ' + j.[Order Type] + ' - ' + CAST(j.[Line] AS VARCHAR),
    DocumentNo = CAST(j.[Order #] AS VARCHAR),
    AmountinLC = j.[Amount Open],
    PurchDoc = j.[Order #],
    ReportingPeriod = @ReportingPeriod,
    FY = @CurrentYear,
    Analyst =
        CASE
            WHEN @CompanyCode IN ('4433', 'PC1') THEN 'Karen Bastek'
            WHEN @CompanyCode = '5620' THEN 'Alla O''Hara'
            WHEN @CompanyCode = 'JDE' THEN 'Sharon Dooley'
            WHEN @CompanyCode IN ('9461', '9462', '9463', '435E', '439Z') THEN 'Irina Shapshevich'
        END,
    CompanyCode = @CompanyCode,
    j.Supplier,
    Name1 = j.Name,
    VendorType =
        CASE
            WHEN LEFT(j.Name, 7) = 'Siemens' THEN 'ICC'
            ELSE '3rd Party'
        END,
    Div = j.[DIV #],
    j.Company,
    CompanyFilter =
        CASE
            WHEN j.Company IN ('31100','40021') THEN j.Company
            ELSE 'All Others'
        END,
    BU = j.[BU #],
    BusinessUnitDescription = j.[Business Unit Description],
    j.Buyer,
    OrderNumber = j.[Order #],
    OrderType = j.[Order Type],
    j.Line,
    ReceiptDate =  CONVERT(varchar(10), j.[Receipt Date], 101),
    ReceiptDoc = j.[Receipt Doc],
    QuantityReceived = j.[Qty Recvd],
    AmountReceived = j.[Amount Rcvd],
    QuantityVouchered = j.[Qty Vouchered],
    AmountVouchered = j.[Amount Vouchered],
    QuantityOpen = j.[Qty Open],
    AmountOpen = j.[Amount Open],
    CurCod = j.[Curr Code],
    ABSVALAmtinLC = ABS(j.[Amount Open]),
    Concatenate = CAST(j.Supplier AS VARCHAR) + CAST(j.[Order #] AS VARCHAR) + j.[Order Type] + CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), j.[Receipt Date], 101) AS VARCHAR) + CAST(j.[Receipt Doc] AS VARCHAR),
    DaysAged = DATEDIFF(DAY, j.[Receipt Date], @CurrentMonth),
    EYAging =
        CASE
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, j.[Receipt Date], @CurrentMonth) > 365 THEN 'h 365 + Days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, j.[Receipt Date], @CurrentMonth) > 180 THEN 'g 180 - 365 Days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, j.[Receipt Date], @CurrentMonth) > 150 THEN 'f 150 - 180 Days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, j.[Receipt Date], @CurrentMonth) > 120 THEN 'e 120 - 150 Days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, j.[Receipt Date], @CurrentMonth) > 90 THEN 'd 90 - 120 Days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, j.[Receipt Date], @CurrentMonth) > 60 THEN 'c 60 - 90 Days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, j.[Receipt Date], @CurrentMonth) > 30 THEN 'b 30 - 60 Days'
            ELSE 'a Current'
        END,
    DaysAgedatMonthEnd = DATEDIFF(DAY, j.[Receipt Date], @NextMonth),
    EYAgingatMonthEnd =
        CASE
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, j.[Receipt Date], @NextMonth) > 365 THEN 'h 365 + Days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, j.[Receipt Date], @NextMonth) > 180 THEN 'g 180 - 365 Days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, j.[Receipt Date], @NextMonth) > 150 THEN 'f 150 - 180 Days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, j.[Receipt Date], @NextMonth) > 120 THEN 'e 120 - 150 Days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, j.[Receipt Date], @NextMonth) > 90 THEN 'd 90 - 120 Days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, j.[Receipt Date], @NextMonth) > 60 THEN 'c 60 - 90 Days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, j.[Receipt Date], @NextMonth) > 30 THEN 'b 30 - 60 Days'
            ELSE 'a Current'
        END,
    RestatedPriorMonth = DATEDIFF(DAY, j.[Receipt Date], @PriorMonth),
    EYAgingPriorMonth =
        CASE
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, j.[Receipt Date], @PriorMonth) < 0 THEN 'False'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, j.[Receipt Date], @PriorMonth) > 365 THEN 'h 365 + Days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, j.[Receipt Date], @PriorMonth) > 180 THEN 'g 180 - 365 Days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, j.[Receipt Date], @PriorMonth) > 150 THEN 'f 150 - 180 Days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, j.[Receipt Date], @PriorMonth) > 120 THEN 'e 120 - 150 Days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, j.[Receipt Date], @PriorMonth) > 90 THEN 'd 90 - 120 Days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, j.[Receipt Date], @PriorMonth) > 60 THEN 'c 60 - 90 Days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, j.[Receipt Date], @PriorMonth) > 30 THEN 'b 30 - 60 Days'
            ELSE 'a Current'
        END,
    Category1 = j.[Category 1],
    GLAcct = CAST(j.[GL Account] AS float),
    ProfitCenter = j.[GL Account],
    Division = @Division,
    BUName = m.[BU Name],
    j.Item,
    GRIRPeriod = @ReportingPeriod

FROM
    dbo.GRIR_JDE j (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN dbo.MOBusinessSegment m (NOLOCK) ON j.[BU #] = m.PRCTR
) AS a
```

Here is the table definition that I am trying to insert the data into:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GRIR_Main](
    [CompanyCode] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [PriceBlk] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [QtyBlk] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [DateBlk] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [TrPrt] [float] NULL,
    [POrg] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PGr] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Plant] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PlantDescription] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PurchReq] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [RequistionerName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [GLAcct] [float] NULL,
    [WBSElement] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [SalesOrder] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Network] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [CostCenter] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Reference] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [DocumentNo] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [ProfitCenter] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Concatenate] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Assignment] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PurchDoc] [float] NULL,
    [VendorType] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Vendor] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Name1] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Material] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [ShortText] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [ABSVALAmtinLC] [float] NULL,
    [GRIRUpdated] [float] NULL,
    [AmountinLC] [float] NULL,
    [Type] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PostingDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [DaysAged] [float] NULL,
    [EYAging] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [DaysAgedatMonthEnd] [float] NULL,
    [EYAgingatMonthEnd] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [RestatedPriorMonth] [float] NULL,
    [EYAgingPriorMonth] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Slippage] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Category1] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Analyst] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [ReportingPeriod] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [FY] [float] NULL,
    [Delegate] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [NAM] [nchar](2) NULL,
    [Supplier] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Division] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Company] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [CompanyFilter] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [BU] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [BusinessUnitDescription] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Buyer] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [OrderNumber] [float] NULL,
    [OrderType] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Line] [float] NULL,
    [ReceiptDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ReceiptDoc] [float] NULL,
    [QuantityReceived] [float] NULL,
    [AmountReceived] [float] NULL,
    [QuantityVouchered] [float] NULL,
    [AmountVouchered] [float] NULL,
    [QuantityOpen] [float] NULL,
    [AmountOpen] [float] NULL,
    [CurCod] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [BUName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Item] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [GRIRPeriod] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Div] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I know I have a type mismatch somewhere, but I can't seem to find it.  Here is the table definition for the source data.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GRIR_JDE](
    [Supplier] [float] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Order #] [float] NULL,
    [Order Type] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Category 1] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Supplier Type] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [DIV #] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Company] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [BU #] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Business Unit Description] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Buyer] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Item Branch Buyer] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Line] [float] NULL,
    [ESN] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Item] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Receipt Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Qty Recvd] [float] NULL,
    [Amount Rcvd] [float] NULL,
    [Qty Vouchered] [float] NULL,
    [Amount Vouchered] [float] NULL,
    [Qty Open] [float] NULL,
    [Amount Open] [float] NULL,
    [Curr Code] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Receipt Doc] [float] NULL,
    [GL Account] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Time Stamp] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Why are you using `float` and `nvarchar(255)` everywhere? That is just sloppy... [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type - Aaron Bertrand - 2009-10-12](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: I have not yet cleaned everything up as needed.  It's a dirty process for now that I was just trying to get to work and then I will go back in and clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it run and clean it up later, use one of the `try_` functions:

In Sql Server 2012 and up: each of these will return `null` when the conversion fails instead of an error.

- [**`try_convert(datatype,val)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx)
- [**`try_cast(val as datatype)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx)
- [**`try_parse(val as datatype [using culture])`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx)

---

Check the type of `j.[Order #]`

you are using it as both a `float` and `nvarchar(255)` in:

```
...
[DocumentNo] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[PurchDoc] [float] NULL,          
...
DocumentNo = j.[Order #],
PurchDoc = j.[Order #],
```

same problem here:

```
GLAcct = j.[GL Account],
ProfitCenter = j.[GL Account],
```

Comment: I thought that was the problem and I tried to CAST it and it still gave me the error.  GLAcct = CAST(j.[GL Account] AS float)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the CAST of the GL Account field to float failed.  I changed the field on the Main table to varchar and it works now.